# Python Beginner - Build a regex with optionnal characters

Tags: python, regex

I try to build a regex with Python which must match on this :

STRING

STRING STRING

STRING (STRING) STRING (STRING)

STRING (STRING) STRING (STRING) STRING (STRING) STRING

I tried to do the job using metacharacter optionnal  ? but for the second pattern STRING STRING it doesn't work : I have just the first character after the first string

```
\w+\s+\w+?
```

gives

> STRING S

but should gives

> STRING STRING

and match on

> STRING
>   STRING STRING

Here is full code :

```
import csv 
import re 
import sys 

fname = sys.argv[1] 

r = r'(\w+) access = (\w+)\s+Vol ID = (\w+)\s+Snap ID = (\w+)\s+Inode = (\w+)\s+IP = ((\d|\.)+)\s+UID = (\w+)\s+Full Path = (\S+)\s+Handle ID: (\S+)\s+Operation ID: (\S+)\s+Process ID: (\d+)\s+Image File Name: (\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+)\s+Primary User Name: (\S+)\s+Primary Domain: (\S+)\s+Primary Logon ID: (.....\s+......)\s+Client User Name: (\S+)\s+Client Domain: (\S+)\s+Client Logon ID: (\S+)'


regex = re.compile(r)

out = csv.writer(sys.stdout) 

f_hdl = open(fname, 'r')
csv_rdr = csv.reader(f_hdl)
header = True

for row in csv_rdr:
    #print row
    if header:
        header = False
    else:
        field = row[-1]

        res = re.search(regex, field)

        if res:
            audit_status = row[3]
            device = row[7]
            date_time = row[0]
            event_id = row[2]
            user = row[6]
            access_source = res.group(1) 
            access_type = res.group(2) 
            volume = res.group(3)
            snap = res.group(4)
            inode = res.group(5)
            ip = res.group(6)
            uid = res.group(8)
            path = res.group(9)
            handle_id = res.group(10)
            operation_id = res.group(11)
            process_id = res.group(12)
            image_file_name = res.group(13)
            primary_user_name = res.group(14)
            primary_domain = res.group(15)
            primary_logon_id = res.group(16)
            client_user_name = res.group(17)
            client_domain = res.group(18)
            client_logon_id = res.group(19)

            print audit_status, device, date_time, event_id, user, access_source, access_type, volume, snap, inode, ip, uid, path
            out.writerow(
                    [audit_status, device, date_time, event_id, user, access_source, access_type, volume, snap, inode, ip, uid, path, handle_id, operation_id, process_id, image_file_name, primary_user_name, primary_domain, primary_logon_id, client_user_name, client_domain, client_logon_id]
                )
        else:
            print 'NOMATCH'
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you tried to do something in Python, show some Python code. And what's logging got to do with anything?

Comment: I put the code and removed the tag logging. My answer is generic but finality is log parsing

Comment: Your code looks nothing like what you describe in the post. Are you trying to match on parens with the (STRING) ? If so, parens are special chars and need to be escaped in the regex like so: \(STRING\)

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand. To parse logs, I need to build a regex which match on the specific STRING pattern I put on the top of the post. Once created, I will insert regex in the code.

Comment: Could you provide a sample log?

Comment: 2014-02-28 00:33:52,2014-02-28 00:33:52,560,Success Audit event,Object Access,Security,LA\Guest,FILER1,"Object Open: Object Server: Security Object Type: File Object Name: NFS access = WRITE Vol ID = 0x1109f4a3 Snap ID = 0x0 Inode = 0xe53fb3 IP = 1.0.0.0 UID = 0x1a7f3 Full Path = /vol/vol1/prod.out Handle ID: - Operation ID: - Process ID: 0 Image File Name: Filer Data SEVEN Primary User Name: - Primary Domain: - Primary Logon ID: (0x0, 0x3e7) Client User Name: - Client Domain: - Client Logon ID: - Accesses: WriteData (or AddFile) AppendData (or AddSubdirectory or CreatePipeInstance)

Comment: What I'm looking for is the regex for data after Accesses:

Comment: Just so I'm clear, are you looking for the regex to capture tokens "WriteData" and "AppendData", while avoiding the other tokens that are in parenthesis between?

Comment: No I want to capture everything in the subfield Accesses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for your regex string:

```
r = '(\\w+) access = (\\w+)\\s+Vol ID = (\\w+)\\s+Snap ID = (\\w+)\\s+Inode = (\\w+)\\s+IP = ((\\d|\\.)+)\\s+UID = (\\w+)\\s+Full Path = (\\S+)\\s+Handle ID: (\\S+)\\s+Operation ID: (\\S+)\\s+Process ID: (\\d+)\\s+Image File Name: (\\w+\\s+\\w+\\s+\\w+)\\s+Primary User Name: (\\S+)\\s+Primary Domain: (\\S+)\\s+Primary Logon ID: (.....\\s+......)\\s+Client User Name: (\\S+)\\s+Client Domain: (\\S+)\\s+Client Logon ID: (\\S+)\\s+Accesses: (.*)'
```

Answer (score 2):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
>   “I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.

If it's a csv file that uses space for separation and parenthesis for quoting, use

```
csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='(')
```

If it's even a simpler case, use the split method on the string and expand it to fill all fields with an empty string:

```
fields = field.split(' ')
fields = [i or j for i, j in map(None, fields, ('',) * 7)]
```

Comment: thx for you help but I don't need to edit the code. I looks for a regex which match on a specific pattern. Issue is only on the regex.